# RSA public key encryption in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, cryptography

I have my public key included in the project as byte array. And I wanted to encrypt password using it.When I tried to create  public key from the byte array I am getting the below given error.

```
SecKeyCreateWithData failed :Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__ObjC.CFError>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50
"RSA public key creation from data failed" UserInfo={NSDescription=RSA public key creation from data failed}))
```

Below given is the code.

```
let attributes : [String : Any] = [
kSecAttrKeyType as String :  kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
kSecAttrKeyClass as String : kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 1024 as AnyObject]

var priKeyCreateError: Unmanaged<CFError>?
_ = SecKeyCreateWithData(PublicKeyDataDevQA as Data as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &priKeyCreateError)

if(priKeyCreateError != nil)
{
    print("\n SecKeyCreateWithData failed :" + String(describing: priKeyCreateError));
}
```

I want to implement this without using any third party library like Swifty RSA.

Public Key used is available [here](https://pastebin.com/QQMDRXLA)

Comment: Please also include the public key bytes in hexadecimals. Without that this question cannot be answered and has to be closed. Shouldn't the key size be of type `CFNumber`? PS winterbash is over, the site should have removed your hat ;)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have updated the question with the public key

Comment: That "key" looks like encoded ASCII or UTF-8. The key should be in binary format, probably PKCS#1 or SubjectPublicKeyInfo (as specified in X.509).

Answer (score 2):

Your key consists of ASCII encoded PEM. To be able to read the key it is likely that you need to decode the PEM (basically base 64 decoding the part in the middle).

Comment: Can you tell me how can u do this?

Comment: here is a detailed answer, you can do it without using any library provided you need ASN.1 parser.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471615/1908892