# `SecKey` object creation for RSA failing, Error Domain Code=-50 "RSA private key creation from data failed swift-iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, rsa

I'm not able to create `SecKey` object from below private key, I did try many answers available here but nothing is helping.

My swift piece of code is as below:

```
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    guard let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: key) else {
        return nil
    }

    var keyAttributes: CFDictionary {
        return [kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: keySize] as CFDictionary
    }

    guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(keyData as CFData, keyAttributes, &error) else {
        print(error.debugDescription) //Error Domain Code=-50 "RSA private key creation from data failed swift-iOS
        return nil
    }
```

The expected result is `secKey` should have valid value and above `guard` should not fail.

Note: Public key conversion to the respective `secKey` is working perfectly fine (the problem is with the only private key while decryption). I have tried removing `\r\n` from the above key.

Comment: Any luck without third party lib?

Comment: refer below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot, found this [Apple thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104753#317856) helpful.
I'm able to manage this ASN.1 parsing using [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) library.

```
    let privateKeySwifty = try PrivateKey(pemEncoded: privateKey)

    let secPrivateKey = try PrivateKey(reference: privateKeySwifty.reference)
```

After digging deeper, I can see, there was a need to stripe the header of `keyData` ([ASN.1 Parsing](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/blob/master/Source/Asn1Parser.swift)).

Comment: Apple document about the Security framework is really poor. Thanks for sharing that.